# Convert power shell script to bash script to rename multiple file names

Tags: bash, powershell

This is my first post and I'm sure it will reveal how new I am with all this, but I would really appreciate any help I can get.

I have a power shell script that renames multiple file names that needs to be converted to bash. I have changed some of the data to conceal the nature of it, so hopefully that doesn't mess anything up.

I essentially want to go from this file name:

```
SSS& Onboarding - Individual Ad HocSegments (13).tsv
```

to this file name:

```
SSSOnboarding_Individual_Ad_HocSegments_20210706.tsv
```

Power shell script

```
Dir SS* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "SSS& Onboarding - ","SSSOnboarding-"}

Dir SS* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "SSS Measurement - ","SSSMeasurement-"}

Dir SS* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".tsv","_" }

Dir SS* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ","_" }

Dir SS* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "_-_","_"}

Dir SS* | %{rename-item $_.name (( $_.name.split("("))[0]+$_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMdd")+".tsv") }
```

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
  rename "SSS& Onboarding -" SSSOnboarding SS*
  rename "SSS& Measurement -" SSSMeasurement SS*
  rename ".tsv" "_" SS*
  rename " " "_" SS*
  rename "-" "_" SS*
  
  ls -1 SS* | while read FILE
    do
        new_file=`echo $FILE | cut -d'(' -f1``date +'%Y%m%d'`'.tsv'
        echo $new_file
        mv $FILE $new_file
        
     done
```

This is what is returned:

```
SSSOnboarding_Individual Ad HocSegments (17)_
```

The bottom part, starting at ls -1 | while read FILE, messes everything up, but everything above it works. Before I added the bottom part, the renames replaced all spaces and dashes with underscores as desired.

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe you can try to explain what is the last part doing for people like me that don't understand power shell scripts?

Comment: @noobforever - It cannot be that "_Before I added the bottom part, the renames replaced all spaces and dashes with underscores as desired._" `rename` only replaced the first space, and the remaining spaces are the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Using [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in a `for` loop with [shell globing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

for file in SS*.tsv; do
  new_file="${file//@(\& |- |\(*\))}"
  new_file="${new_file// /_}"
  extension="${new_file##*_}"
  new_filename="${new_file%"$extension"}"
  echo mv -v "$file" "$new_filename$(date '+%Y%m%d')$extension"
done
```

---

- Create a backup as always when editing files/filenames etc.
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output so `mv` can rename the files.

Comment: Thank you Jetchisel! That worked like a charm. I had to make one tiny adjustment on line 3 to get rid of the ampersand by deleting the space between \& and the | to equal this: \&|. Awesome job!

Comment: @noobforever, Glad I could help out,  please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers